# How can I add the +0430 timezone to Drupal 6?

Tags: datetime

As you know, Drupal 6 doesn't have the +0430 timezone in the date/time page. I want to add this specific item into timezone drop-down list.

Does anybody know about this core patching? How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for my question.

Go to modules > systems

open **system.module**

Then find **_system_zonelist** function

```
/**
 * Generate an array of time zones and their local time&date.
 */
function _system_zonelist() {
  $timestamp = time();
  $zonelist = array(-11, -10, -9.5, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4.5, -4, -3.5, -3, -2.5, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3.5, 4, 5, 5.5, 5.75, 6, 6.5, 7, 8, 9, 9.5, 10, 10.5, 11, 11.5, 12, 12.75, 13, 14);
  $zones = array();
  foreach ($zonelist as $offset) {
    $zone = $offset * 3600;
    $zones[$zone] = format_date($timestamp, 'custom', variable_get('date_format_long', 'l, F j, Y - H:i') .' O', $zone);
  }
  return $zones;
}
```

All you need is adding 4.5 value to $zonelist array.

The array must be

```
$zonelist = array(-11, -10, -9.5, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4.5, -4, -3.5, -3, -2.5, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3.5, 4,4.5, 5, 5.5, 5.75, 6, 6.5, 7, 8, 9, 9.5, 10, 10.5, 11, 11.5, 12, 12.75, 13, 14);
```

Comment: Plus, file an issue to drupal core project so that they add the time zone and free people from hacking the core :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this looks like a problem in PHP. The timezone is being used by the Date module, and that contains [date_timezone_abbr()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!date!date_api!date_api.module/function/date_timezone_abbr/6), which uses PHP's [timezone_abbreviations_list()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.listabbreviations.php).

Only the keys are stored, and the PHP function is being used. I am afraid there is no way out of this, unless there is a way to convince PHP.

When I tried the following code, I get 4, not 4.5.

```
$a = timezone_abbreviations_list();
echo $a['aft'][0]['offset'] / 3600;
```

Comment: Nobody Has a an answer for my question ? :(

Comment: try this if you can change your system http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776392/incomplete-list-of-timezones-generated-by-php

Comment: I visited it. Unfortunately I am not pro in PHP programming. I am searching a way to modify timezone list in DRUPAL 6.